# How can we set the NSLayoutConstraint values dynamically in Storyboard

Tags: ios

Can we set the values of NSLayoutConstraint dynamically in Storyboard for different iOS devices.

```
    @IBOutlet var topnIconCnst: NSLayoutConstraint!

    if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS {
        topnIconCnst.constant = 20
    }
    else if  DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_5 {
        topnIconCnst.constant = 60
    }
    else if  DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_6 {
        topnIconCnst.constant = 70
 }
```

Comment: You can do this also using size classes on interface builder

Comment: Size classes is only for rotation, and going between iPhone-iPad, so your comment is INVALID!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` after you set the new constraint value.